# Laravel 5 saving and updating models with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

First thank for watch my question and sorry for my poor english.

I have two models :

User Model  with the next relationship:

```
public function datosAlumno()
{
    return $this->hasOne('sj\Models\DatosAlumno','alumno_id');
}
```

and DatosAlumno model :

```
public function alumno(){
    return $this->belongsTo('sj\Models\User','alumno_id');
}
```

if I print with dd(\Request::all()) :

```
array:16 [▼
    "_method" => "PUT"
    "_token" => "vnQp4msoo8UHGan5m4v8VYvX1kKYx8HnbhqaywZH"
    "rut" => "111111111111"
    "nombre" => "AAAAAAAAAA"
    "apellido_paterno" => "BBBBBBBBBBB"
    "apellido_materno" => "CCCCCCCCCCCC"
    "sexo" => "masculino"
    "comuna_id" => "13"
    "direccion" => "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR"
    "telefono_fijo" => "14876955"
    "telefono_movil" => "3333333333"
    "fecha_nacimiento" => "2000-11-03"
    "email" => "michelle76@conroy.com"
    "datosAlumno" => array:1 [▼
        "apoderado_id" => "37"
    ]
    "password" => ""
    "password_confirmation" => ""
]
```

I'm trying save or update "datosAlumno" but when I use save, push or update the field doesn't change in the database

```
public function update($id)
{
    $user = User::with('datosAlumno')->find($id);
    $user->fill(\Request::all());
    $user->push();
}
```

If I do `dd($user->datosAlumno)` after to fill with `\Request::all()` I get this :

```
DatosAlumno {#297 ▼
    #table: "datos_alumno"
    #fillable: array:2 [▼
        0 => "alumno_id"
        1 => "apoderado_id"
    ]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 1
         "alumno_id" => 97
         "apoderado_id" => 15
         "deleted_at" => null
         "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
         "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ]
    #original: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "alumno_id" => 97
        "apoderado_id" => 15
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the data to the `DatosAlumno` model (`hasOne` relation) before you push to database. Currently you set the data only to the user model. So this will work:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $user = User::with('datosAlumno')->find($id);
    $user->fill(\Request::all());
    $user->datosAlumno->fill(\Request::get('datosAlumno'));
    $user->push();
}
```

By the way it is a good practice to **ALWAYS** write your function and variable names in English. This way the code is more readable and easy to understand for anyone that will work on this code after you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will consider your recommendation.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying something very similar to what you have here:  $Rental = Rental::with('region', 'location')->find($id); where I can fill the direct rental fields $Rental->fill($requestData); and have it persist, but when I try to fill the location data: $Rental->location->fill($otherRequestData); it doesn't persist.  I tried $Rental->push(), save(), update(), but each time the location data never persists.  Do you know why this might be happening?  The $Rental object looks good in Tinker with both relationship data included.

Comment: @mtpultz Please post your case as separate question and include some code samples from your class declaration :)

Comment: Hi, I've posted a separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31463650/1148107